# React/NodeJS - Web page doesn't work when go at localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, web-applications

first of all i'd like to say that i'm a new developer of React and NodeJS.

I want use this technologies:
- React as a client
- NodeJS as a server
- Webpack for build my files.

My project structure is the follow:

my-application/

webpack.server.js

webpack.client.js

server.js

client/client.js

client/app.js

client/components/header.js

client/components/mainLayout.js

client/components/footer.js

The header and footer files are not important so i'm not writing here.
The important file are the following:

**mainLayout.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// import component
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';

class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Header />

              {this.props.children}

            <Footer />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainLayout;
```

**app.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import MainLayout from './components/mainLayout'

const AppComponent = () =>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact render={props => (
            <MainLayout>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </MainLayout>
        )} />
    </Switch>
;

export default AppComponent;
```

**client.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import AppComponent from './app';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AppComponent />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';

import AppComponent from './client/app'

var app = express();

const PORT = 3000;

app.use("/", express.static("build/public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(<AppComponent />)
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Now browse to localhost:3000'));
```

Run my project:

```
npm run build

npm run dev
```

but when i'm going at http://localhost:3000 my page response is 
{"key":null,"ref":null,"props":{},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}.

I don't understand why i have the error, something probably escapes me but i don't what.

Can you help me please?

Thanks you in advance,
AS

Comment: maybe because nodejs and react are running in the same port and I don't think that is possible or you need to change something to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running both front and back end on the same port. Go to package.json for your react app and replace your start script with the following script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3007 && react-scripts start",
     // the rest of your scripts
}
```

This will be the first step for resolving your issue. If you keep getting errors after that, let us know what are they.

Comment: Thank, this help me!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the application again using `npm`.

In the command I entered: `npm start` in the application folder after this it worked again.

Comment: I also went into the command terminal and just typed in 'npm start' and it worked excellently.

Answer (score 0):

In App.js, add Routes in the import. Use element instead of component.

For Example:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
<Navbar />    
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element = {</>}/>    
        <Route path="/" exact element = {</>}/>
      </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Consider adding example code or more detail to explain your answer.

Comment: Check this out @EthanMcTague

Answer (score -1):

This can be from the browser you are using.
Copy the local host address on your address bar and paste on a different browser, Chrome recommended.
This is based on personal experience. It kept rolling on Opera browser until I opened it on Chrome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How exactly is this not clear to you? Anyone who has tried using React knows that Local host has an address that appears on the browser's address bar after npm start. I suggested, based on personal experience, copying that address from the address bar or from CMD and pasting it on another browser. How is that not clear? I have seen shorter answers here.